# What does this lambda expression mean?

Tags: java

It looks like an anonymous class. I didn't find any article talk about this usage of lambdas.

```java
   public Supplier<Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>> supplier() {
        return () -> new HashMap<>() { //todo what does this mean?
            {
                this.put(false, new ArrayList<>());
                this.put(true, new ArrayList<>());
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Creates a new `HashMap` and puts 2 `ArrayLists` in it

Comment: ...the above, as an implementation of [`Supplier<T>` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of different things going on here.

The method returns a `Supplier<Map<...>>`. The lambda expression `() -> new HashMap<>() ...` returns an instance of the interface `Supplier` which returns a `HashMap`.

Also, it doesn't return a plain `HashMap`; an anonymous subclass of `HashMap` is being created here because of the outer `{ ... }`.

The inner `{ ... }` is an [instance initializer block](https://dzone.com/articles/instance-initializers-java) which is used to put stuff in the `HashMap` (two entries with keys `true` and `false` and each an `ArrayList` as the value).

This is using the [double-brace initialization trick](https://www.jesperdj.com/2016/07/19/dont-use-the-double-brace-initialization-trick/). (That link points to a blogpost written by me that explains why I dislike that trick).

A better way to write this (if you're using Java 9 or newer) that doesn't use the double-brace initialization trick is like this:

```
public Supplier<Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>> supplier() {
    return () -> Map.of(
        false, new ArrayList<>(),
        true, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method returns a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html). And when someone uses the created [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) by calling its get-method, a new [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is created and two empty [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)s are inserted into it.

```
System.out.println(supplier().get());
```

would result into the console-output

```
{false=[], true=[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you run this piece of code but I tried to run it and I have to add

```
return () -> new HashMap<Boolean, List<Integer>>()
```

Otherwise, @Jesper already gave you a good answer. 
Below, it is a little explanation about lambda expressions.

```
() -> ...
```

is a lambda expression with zero parameters. 
You can use a lambda expression as a parameter, but you need to have a `@FunctionalInterface`. 
You can look at `forEach` method from `Iterable` class from Java.

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> var1)
```

In this case the consumer is a `FunctionalInterface`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T>
```

Basically, with lambda, you can send the body of the method as parameter. If you have a list with Strings named `stringList`, you can pass as parameter for `forEach` a lambda expression in order to print all the elements:

```
stringList.forEach(elem -> {
            System.out.println(elem);
        });
```

This lambda expression has one parameter, `elem`. You can have zero, one, or many parameters in a lambda expression.